# Can I change the /home folder after ubuntu installation?

Tags: home-directory, fstab

I had installed Ubuntu 11.10 on a clear 40gb hd, but now i have a 100gb partition that i want to use as a /home folder, is there a problem to simple use fstab to change the mounting point?

I'm thinking to copy/paste all the archives in actual /home folder to this 100gb partition and then change the mounting point in fstab.

Edit: I will not make this because this 100gb partition is ntfs type, so no donuts for me.

Comment: Dublicate question answered
http://askubuntu.com/questions/20287/how-to-re-mount-a-different-partition-as-home

Answer (score 26):

Check out the howto: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Partitioning/Home/Moving

The basic steps are as follows:

1. Setup your new partition.
2. Backup and edit your `fstab` file (`/etc/fstab`) to mount the new partition as `/media/home` (just for the time being) and reboot.
3. Use `rsync` to migrate all data from `/home` into `/media/home`.
4. Edit `fstab` again so the new partition mounts as `/home` instead of `/media/home` but not reboot just yet.
5. Move `/home` to `/old_home` and reboot.
6. Delete `/old_home`.

Comment: Thank you, your answer is pretty simple and yet so explanatory.

Comment: I know nothing about the fstab, could you detail what I need to do on it?

Comment: You need to learn what [fstab](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Fstab) is, and how to edit it. It's really not that hard.

Comment: Thanks. Your answer made that linked article less daunting!!