# Using existing home directories in different partition to Ubuntu

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, mount

All of the questions I've looked at in respect of this issue relate to moving an existing home to another partition and I don't want to do that.  I had to reload Ubuntu 18.04.1 on my machine and thankfully it loaded Ubuntu into sda/dev8, whilst leaving all my data where it was on dev/sda10.  The sda10 data was produced whilst running 16.4.04 (and previous versions).

What I now want to do is configure my system so that it uses and mounts dev/sda10 as home.  I want to delete the home directories on dev/sda8.  I do have backup copies of my data, but don't want to have to restore and setup the different programs I run, unless absolutely necessary.

Can someone please help explain how to do this?

Comment: What is "sda/dev10"? I never saw that notation before and what filessystem does sda/dev10 have? Next to that: see `/etc/fstab`. That's where alle the disks are mounted and you will find a /home there if it is a different partition. You can switch the UUID to "sda/dev10" there. You can not however set TWO partitions that both have /home as a root directory.

Comment: Does [How to re-mount a different partition as /home?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/20287/how-to-re-mount-a-different-partition-as-home) answer your questions?

Comment: @Rinzwind - sorry, got my sda and dev mixed up - have corrected original post. sd10 is ext4 format. Will look at fstab. I definitely don't want two partitions as home.

Comment: @steeldriver - Many thanks. I'd started reading the detailed instructions the post linked to, but dismissed them as they dealt with creating a new partition and copying existing home directories to it - which I don't want to do. Also there was some debate about how correct some of the posts were. I'll look further into it and give it a go.  Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As steeldriver said, the answer lay in the post he/she referred to. All I had to do was edit the fstab file, as per the instructions. Home now points to my sda10 partition.